# How to force Git to take full pages

Tags: git

I messed up something in Git at some point and what's now on our `devserver` branch is wrong.  What's in my `cptools` branch is correct.  But when I do:

```
git checkout devserver
git merge cptools
```

it doesn't register that the two files are different.  Apparently I committed them to `devserver` without meaning to.  Is there any way to uncommit them from `devserver` so I can merge them back in?  I need Git to take the full page from `cptools`.  How do I do that?

Comment: I think what I'm asking about is rolling back, except I don't know which the bad commit is.  Is there any way to just remove the page?

Comment: What do you mean with page? Do you mean a commit?

Comment: A file.  I'm new to Git and am not sure which commits have which files in them.  I need to remove a file from the `devserver` branch so Git will see it as a new file and take it.

Comment: I know that's not the way Git is supposed to work, but it's what I need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Looking at branches

Take a look at

- "**`git branch -v`**" to see the branches list,
- "**`git checkout branch_name`**" to switch to a branch.

### Looking at commits

Look at **`git log branch_name_here`**:

```
$ git log
commit 65471553a1f67650e1e3511463ffc881ce9724b8
Author: The Wookie <thewookied@SO.com>
Date:   Sun Feb 10 23:12:21 2013 -0500

    Test commit 3

commit d0fc7ffb0bc3276c6bbc20b2c8ad1e1a4e46ff3b
Author: The Wookie <thewookied@SO.com>
Date:   Sun Feb 10 21:59:56 2013 +1030

    Test commit 2

commit b720fdc15f2b47e8e169a5ea9372de4814ae0724
Author: The Wookie <thewookied@SO.com>
Date:   Sun Feb 10 21:59:07 2013 +1030

    Test commit 1
```

To see what exacrtly a commit did, **`git diff ref1 ref2`**:

```
$ git diff d0fc7ffb0bc3276c6bbc20b2c8ad1e1a4e46ff3b 65471553a1f67650e1e3511463ffc881ce9724b8

diff --git a/file.py b/file.py
index 14017fc..31e30f0 100644
--- a/file.py
+++ b/file.py
@@ -42,23 +42,29 @@ class Foo(object):
         self.cursor  = self.connection.cursor()
         if (not self.db_exists):
             # create the db
-            self.cursor.execute('''DROP TABLE foo''')
-            self.connection.commit()
...
```

### Undoing commits

Do **`git reset --hard old_ref`** to remove commit from log and reset file changes it did.

I.e. **`git reset --hard d0fc7ffb0bc3276c6bbc20b2c8ad1e1a4e46ff3b`** would undo the latest change and remove it from commit log, leaving only commits 1 and 2.

### Don't forget

1. Keep backups.
2. Do not push until you are confident that everything is right.

Comment: That's very thorough. Wow!  But what's in `devserver` was NEVER right.  So I can't rollback.  I need to overwrite and Git isn't seeing my changes.  It thinks what in `devserver` is correct when it isn't even close to being the same`.

Comment: If git isn't seeing your changes, `git add path/to/file` while a relevant branch is active?

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't thought about that.  I'll try that.

Comment: That does nothing.  `git status` doesn't show the new file added, apparently because its already there.

Comment: OK. Then the file is already in the tree. `git log path/to/file` to see its history.

Comment: Something was really messed up.  After I did the `log` call, Git suddenly saw all my changes.  Thanks, @gryllida.

Comment: No problem, good luck fixing things. Don't forget to stab whoever broke things, if it wasn't you. ;-)